# How do I generate a random variable whose CDF is the product of given CDFs?

Tags: random-variable, random-generation

I am looking at a finite set of independent random variables ${\left\{ {{X_i}} \right\}_{1 \le i \le n}}$ with CDF ${F_i}$, with the aim of generating a random variable such that it has the CDF ${G_1}(x) = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {F_i}(x)$. I was thinking about the usual theorems, like $F({X_i})$ is uniformly distributed if F is continuous, but we haven't been given anything about the random variables beyond that they are independent of one another. There should be some explicit $h\left( {{X_1},{X_{2,}}...,{X_n}} \right)$ such that it is distributed accoridng to $G_1$. Any possible ideas, any angles you reckon I should try?

Comment: Welcome to CV.This is the distribution of $\max\{X_1, \,X_2, \dots, \, X_n\}$ provided that the $X_i$ are independent.

Comment: Of course. The event that all the $X_i$ are less than some x, is equivalent to the event that the maximum of all the $X_i$ is less than that x. Thank you so much. Do you reckon this can be extended? Like for $\mathop \Pi \limits_{i = 1}^n (1 - {F_i}(x))$ the underlying event that all $X_i$ are greater than some X, is equivalent to the minimum of these events being greater than x? And then $1 - \left( {\mathop \Pi \limits_{i = 1}^n (1 - {F_i}(x))} \right)$ the  underlying event can be seen to be the minimum of $X_i$ being less than x? Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you wish to generalize your question, please edit the question.